# Merge 4 matrix in R

Tags: r

I have 4 matrices in R (Counts_CRep1,Counts_CRep2,Counts_NRep1,Counts_NRep2) that i would like to merge into 1.

The matrix look like this:

```
              [,1]
ENSG00000000003     0
ENSG00000000005     0
ENSG00000000419     0
ENSG00000000457     0
```

As a result I would like to have something similar to this

```
                     Counts_CRep1 Counts_CRep2 Counts_NRep1 Counts_NRep2 
ENSG00000000003           0           0            0            0
ENSG00000000005           0           0            0            0
ENSG00000000419           0           0            0            0
ENSG00000000457           0           0            0            0
```

.....

Any suggestion of how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `cbind`

```
cbind(Counts_CRep1, Counts_CRep2, Counts_NRep1, Counts_NRep2)
```

or `data.frame`

```
data.frame(Counts_CRep1, Counts_CRep2, Counts_NRep1, Counts_NRep2)
```

With the latter technique the names of the objects automatically will be used as column names (unless column names are present in the objects).